# Generic class type parameter

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

**Preconditions:**

There is a third party library providing the following code (can **NOT** be changed):

```
/**
* @param <T> result type of the request
* @param <U> exception type of the request
**/
public interface Request<T, U extends ThirdPartyException> {}


public class ConcreteRequest<T> implements Request<T, ConcreteException> {}


public class SimpleRequest<T> implements Request<T, SimpleException> {}


public class Api {
    public void doConcreteRequest(ConcreteRequest<ConcreteType1> request);
    public void doSimpleRequest(SimpleRequest<ConcreteType2> request);
    public void doAnotherRequest(SimpleRequest<ConcreteType1> request);
}
```

---

**Requirements:**

I want to build a simple class to mock those requests and add some common functionality to the mocks.

What I have so far:

```
public class MockRequestBuilder<T extends Request<R, U>, R, U extends ThirdPartyException> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public MockRequestBuilder(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T build() {
        T mock = mock(type);
        // Code to add additional stuff to mock here
        return mock;
    }
}
```

---

**Problem:**

How do I build a concrete, typesafe instance of such a mock request using the `MockRequestBuilder`?

Obviously

```
new MockRequestBuilder<SimpleRequest<ConcreteType1>, ConcreteType1, SimpleException>(SimpleRequest.class);
```

does not work as `SimpleRequest.class` does not provide information about the other two generic types.

The second way I found is to use

```
new MockRequestBuilder<SimpleRequest, ConcreteType1, SimpleException>(SimpleRequest.class);
```

But this will of course return a `SimpleRequest` without type information instead of the needed `SimpleRequest<ConcreteType1>` when the method `build();` is called.

Comment: I'm lost what is your goal exactly at the end? what do you want to create?

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstandings, I was a bit in a hurry when I wrote the question. I rewrote it to be more clear.